# Fatou's Lemma for sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, lebesgue-integral

Is there some kind of *Fatou's Lemma for Sequences* along the following lines:

Suppose I have a doubly indexed array $\{a_{n,k}\}_{n,k =1}^{\infty}$ and I know the following facts:

1. For each fixed $n$, $\liminf_{k \to \infty}a_{n,k} \geq a_n$.
2. For each fixed $k$, the sequence $\{a_{n,k}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is monotone (let's say decreasing).
3. $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is also monotone decreasing.

Then, can I conclude something like:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}\liminf_{k \to \infty}a_{n,k} \leq \liminf_{k \to \infty}\lim_{n \to \infty}a_{n,k}?
$$
The limit in $n$ is playing the role of the Lebesgue integral (which is a type of monotone limit). I think Hypothesis 1. is kind of redundant, but I'll leave it there anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Counterexample: $a_{n,k}=2^{k-n}$, $a_n=0$.

As $k\to\infty$, $a_{n,k}\to\infty$, so $\liminf_k a_{n,k} = \infty > a_n$.
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\liminf_{k\to\infty}a_{n,k} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\infty=\infty$$
$$\liminf_{k\to\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n,k} = \liminf_{k\to 0}0=0$$
That inequality points in the wrong direction.

There might be something to salvage, but it'll take reversing some inequality signs in the conditions.

Comment: Ah yes. Perhaps the monotone sequences should be increasing; I guess that's more like an integral of non-negative functions that way.